# How to play the html5 video in IE8 Browsers

Tags: html5-video, telerik-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have develop a MVC3 Application in that i have use html5 video controls when i run the application it is playin Chrome but when i try to play in IE8 Browser it doesn't play the video just it show the white page only...How to play the video in all Browsers please help me..

Here is my code what i did in my page

```
<video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg"
    width="640" height="360">
    <source src="../../Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <%-- <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />--%>
    <source src="../../Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"
        width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'../../Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg"
            width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Your title refers to html5 video but your question is about Flash video, isn't it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's a nice standard way of setting up HTML5 video with flash and other fallbacks.

Please see [Video for Everybody](http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/) for a nice generator of HTML5 tags with fallback options.

Alternatively, here's [another great library, with JS/CSS code to make it work consistently](http://videojs.com).

Comment: Hi..thank youuu somuch it is working.. actually i have test this video in my local system for that i gave src="from my server path"  then how can i play this.Because in this link he gave the source like http://url... insted of this what i give src path ..please

Comment: I'd like to answer, but I'm confused what you are asking.  For either version, you just need an absolute path to the file.  If you are testing a local version, use `file://<<path_to_file>>`, where `<<path_to_file>` should be the full path.

Comment: Ok i have post my modified code in my Question  please check it once.. i want change in this url "<param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'../../Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />

Comment: The only player from link 1 which is working fine on IE8 for me is JW Player

Answer (score 0):

I have used following way to fix playback issue for IE and this worked for me.

```
<video id=0 controls width="640" height="360">
<source src="new/db.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="new/db.webm" type='video/webm' >
<source src="new/db.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="500" height="500">
  <param name="movie" value="db.swf">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0">
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="../../Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="db.swf" width="500" height="500">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0">
    <param name="expressinstall" value="../../Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>

</video>

<script type="text/javascript">swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");</script>
<script src="../../Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> // you can download swfobject_modified here

http://code.google.com/p/fanarshavin/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_modified.js&can=2&q=

Answer (score -1):

I'm failed to switch between videos on page with JWPlayer in IE8. Moreover, its JS API simply doesn't work in IE8.
There are also top players: medialement, VideoJS, SublimeVideo. So, I'm trying mediaelement now.