# Html 5 video tag is not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, video, tags

Hello i am working on html5 and use video tag of html5 to play video.
It is correctly working on all browser except IE7 and IE8.On these two version of IE it is not working.
Then i follow steps given on this link   http://html5media.info/ but i can't me.
so please help me regarding this.

Comment: IE7 and IE8 does not understand HTML5 audio tag. You have to provide flash for that.

Comment: Are you sure that the html5media script is being loaded?

Comment: IE7 and IE8 don't natively support the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags. You might want to try something like [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). If I understand the project correctly, the JavaScript library brings IE up to speed with modern web standards.

Comment: No support `video` tag or most html5 until IE9.  Go with Flash for IE.  IE7 in particular will have a slower JS engine and be on slower computers, so trying to do some kind of polyfill on this level is just asking for a headache.

Comment: Refer this [thread][1], it might help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922493/how-to-play-the-html5-video-in-ie8-browsers

Answer (score 5):

you can use the html5media library to use video tag of html5. It is a javascript library. 
Use the below tag in your page.

```
<script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.6/html5media.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alternatively you can following : http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_448aed2001019gut.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the embed tag for video tag to work in ie8 and below.

`

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  ** <embed src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" wmode="opaque">
         <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
     </embed>**
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

`