# play mp4 video in ie7,8,9 firefox, chrome and safari using the HTML5 player - possible?

Tags: html, cross-browser

Is it possible to use only a mp4 video and the HTML5 player in  ie7,8,9  firefox, chrome and safari

I've seen these links
http://blog.beverlyguillermo.com/post/14813549122/ie7-and-html5-video

and
http://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

and
http://designwebkit.com/web-and-trends/10-good-html5-video-players-website/

Have you ever done this

Thanks

Comment: If you could use jQuery, check this http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: HTML5 is not even recognized by IE 7 & 8. You can use a HTML5 player that degrades to flash for IE7&8

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://code.google.com/p/video4all/ . Its a nice way you can integrate with all the browsers you have listed

If you are not satisfied try the answer here :- [How to play the html5 video in IE8 Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922493/how-to-play-the-html5-video-in-ie8-browsers)