# HTML5 video sizing issue in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, sizing, column-sizing

Using html5 video tag inside of a bootstrap framework. Works great in every browser minus IE 9 or less.
Here is the site URL for reference: http://www.randyrosario/Website/TimSimmon/MLM.html.com
Any assistance would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in < IE9

http://caniuse.com/#feat=video

Comment: Cannot help you with that, but try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922493/how-to-play-the-html5-video-in-ie8-browsers

Comment: Thank you for that link! It has provided useful information! I appreciate you!!